# Determine the index of image in a div I've clicked on

Tags: jquery

I've got some code like so:

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="/media/img/banana.png" />
    <img src="/media/img/apple.png" />
    <img src="/media/img/lobster.png" />
    <img src="/media/img/charismatic_duck.png" />               
</div>
```

What I'd like is to work out what the following code needs so that it logs 1 if I click the first image, 2 if I click the next etc.

```
$("#thumbs img").click(function(){
    console.log(_____WHAT GOES HERE?_____)
});
```

I'm aware that I could add IDs (image1, image2 etc) and use that to work it out, but I'd like a cleaner way if there is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
console.log( $(this).index() + 1 )
```

The `.index()` method returns a zero-based index number of the `img` that was clicked (in relation to its siblings).

I added `+ 1` to give you the 1-based index that you wanted.

- http://api.jquery.com/index/

There are various other ways of calling `.index()`. With no arguments, it behaves as I described above.

Comment: Ah, index, not indice! Thanks!